# CSS Cascade: !important vs animation

Tags: html, css, css-animations, css-cascade

In the CSS Cascading and Inheritance module it is explained that the declarations with the !important annotation have a greater importance than the styles whose origin is an animation.

When testing on my own I realize that no style can prevent a css property from being overwritten when the animation is running.

Example:

```css
.box{
  background-color: green!important;
  animation: animacion 2s; 
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
@keyframes animacion {
  from{
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  to{
    background-color: blue;
    margin-left: 50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

In this example when the animation is running the `background-color` is changed.

If I use `animation-fill-mode: forwards` to make the value given in the last keyframe be retained by the element this value will be overwriting the value with `!important`.

This behavior seems to me contrary to what the specification says or perhaps I have not understood what they are trying to say.

Comment: what browser are you using to test? the animation should not run

Comment: Animation runs on chrome, using a mac

Comment: On my browser the animation slides from left to right but color stays green throughout

Answer (score 0):

This makes sence since the animation is a transformation, and the background color is a state. if you want to disable the animation you can overwrite this also. They are simply 2 diffent things. Basicly the box is green before and after the animation, just not during.